# makeDir name from a list of strings

Tags: 3dsmax, maxscript

I'm trying to use makeDir to create three directories inside another directory that the user chooses, but the name of this new directories came from a list of strings:

```
_renderPath = getSavePath

_dirNames = ["THUMBNAIL", "NORMALS", "WIREFRAMES"]

for i in _dirNames do(

    makeDir (_renderPath + "\\" + i)

)
```

But the scripting listener always says *"Unable to convert: "THUMBNAIL" to type: Float"*.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to make a list is:

```
_dirNames = #("THUMBNAIL","NORMALS","WIREFRAME")
```

Comment: MAXScript does not provide a primitive _list_ type. This is an _array_. The [documentation](https://help.autodesk.com/view/MAXDEV/2023/ENU/?guid=GUID-34C253DE-0F9F-4FB5-BBB1-4233F2C32477) is your friend, here. See the heading _"Entering Arrays in MAXScript"_ in the provided link.

Answer (score 0):

lists = array in max

[Array Literals](https://help.autodesk.com/view/MAXDEV/2021/ENU/?guid=GUID-F44E766A-34AA-4F90-9776-E8A1C4D7CF33)

[ ] is a [2d or 3d point literal](https://help.autodesk.com/view/MAXDEV/2021/ENU/?guid=GUID-A2C25DDF-2FC1-456B-90C2-B91D98296C3F)